# BigQuery: How can I append results to an existing table?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I want to run a query and append its results to an existing table.
I was able to save a query results as a table, set its scheme, but I can't find how to append new data to it.

If the aggregated table can be partitioned by ingestion date it will be great.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#insert_statement

Answer (score 2):

Once you have your table defined, you can always append data to it by setting it as the target table for your query results, and setting the write disposition to be `WRITE_APPEND`. This will basically append whatever your query results are to the existing target table `dataset.table`.

Also, if your table is date partitioned and you want to append to a specific partition, you can do so by setting the target table of your query to be `dataset.table$YYYMMDD` and again using the `WRITE_APPEND` disposition.

Comment: Thank you @khan, it looks like the right way, however, I'm not sure how I can select the correct `source` table. When I run the table manually, I use a table named `event_$YYYYMMDD` (partitioned), now I want to take the values from the day before and apply it to a correlating partition on the target table